# Detect TD element by inner value and move it to be last

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

Trying to better my skills with ECMAScript with moving elements and their content. Regarding my scenario, Once the DOM is ready, I want to...

- Check to see within my fourth `<tr>`, if there is a `<td>` that has label element with the value of "None".
- If true, and it's not the last `<td>`, copy that entire `<td>` and append it to that `<tr>` so that its the last `<td>` in that row.
- Delete the original `<td>` that had the value of none.

My HTML in code

```html
<table id="myItems">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input id="item10"><label for="item10">House</label></td>
  <td><input id="item11"><label for="item11">None</label></td>
  <td><input id="item12"><label for="item12">Car</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I have tried so far, but needs to be improved....

```js
   //get table name
    const mtarget = 'myItems';

    //check if exists
    if (document.getElementById(mtarget)) {

        //make the swap
        function init() {      
            //if so, target the specific table
            const mtable = document.querySelector("#" + mtarget);
            const lastrow = mtable.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')[3];
            //within it, move the none <td> to the end of existing <tr>
            const tdorgNone = lastrow.querySelectorAll('td')[1];
            const tdcloneNone = tdorgNone.cloneNode(true);
            lastrow.appendChild(tdcloneNone);
            tdorgNone.remove();
        }

        init();
```

I feel like I'm close, but notice I am not targeting the correct `<td>` by the label value. I need a deeper understanding of finding the `<td>` I want by knowing the inner values.  How can I improve this code via ECMAScript in 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a query string, you can pretty concisely select the children of the `<tr>` you want in an array. Then, you can `.find` the `<td>` with the label - if it exists, then just call `appendChild` on the parent `<tr>`, and the `<td>` will be removed from its previous position and put at the bottom.

```js
const mtarget = 'myItems';
const tds = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#${mtarget} tr:nth-child(4) td`)];
const noneTd = tds.find(td => td.children[1].textContent === 'None');
if (noneTd) {
  noneTd.parentElement.appendChild(noneTd);
}
```

```html
<table id="myItems">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="item10"><label for="item10">House</label></td>
      <td><input id="item11"><label for="item11">None</label></td>
      <td><input id="item12"><label for="item12">Car</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```